# What game is this sound file from?

Tags: game-identification

I have uploaded it to [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/zerostack/red-alert-24).  The only information that I can provide as the original title was "Red Alert" and a friend gave this file to me a few years ago which I eventually made into a ringtone.

I have played all Command and Conquer games (Red Alert Series) and know that this isn't from any of those games.

What game is this from?

Comment: That sounds like Mega Man.  NES-era.

Comment: Yeah it does. Red Alert is a group in the Mega Man universe, as well: http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Alert

Comment: that was interesting.  Has a similar cadence like MegaMan or Capcom games.  I agree though, it has to be in the NES-era due to the limited channels.

It could be a custom made track as well. That's a high probability right now as well.

Comment: Its a nice tune! Never played a Metal Gear game before, this is how i found it: http://bfy.tw/6UNq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like its the soundtrack of the first Metal Gear game:

As you can see on the [Soundtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_/_Solid_Snake:_Music_Compilation_of_Hideo_Kojima_/_Red_Disc#Track_listing): 14   Red Alert   5:12

Comment: I'm going to note that the soundtrack list you linked to is a Remix album and not the OST.